# Converting an IQueryable<int?> to IQueryable<int> after nulls have been removed

Tags: c#, linq, nullable, iqueryable

I have and an `IQueryable<int>` and an `IQueryable<int?>` from which the nulls have been removed using a `Where()` in an earlier stage of processing. I now wish to perform a `UNION()` between the two queryables but as one is of a nullable type and the other not I can't.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

If your `IQueryable<int?>` object has no nulls, then you should just be able to "convert" it into an `IQueryable<int>` using a .Select() call.

```
int?[] withNulls = new int?[] { 1, null, 0, 2, 3, 4, null, 1, 6 };
int[] noNulls = new int[] { 10, -4, 30, 6, 7, 8, -2, -3 };

                                                                 // This is the step you need.
var removedNulls = withNulls.AsQueryable().Where(n => n.HasValue).Select(n => n.Value);
var union = removedNulls.Union(noNulls);
```

Printing `removedNulls` and `union` gives me

```
1 0 2 3 4 1 6 
1 0 2 3 4 6 10 -4 30 7 8 -2 -3
```

Comment: If it has already been determined that `HasValue` is true, `GetValueOrDefault()` should be used because `Value` evaluates `HasValue` again.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that. Thanks for the info! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can just project them using `Select` and `Value`.

```
queryable.Select(i => i.Value)
```